# Check condition with boolValue method

Tags: objective-c

I sometimes see following condition:

```
^(NSNumber *value) {
        if([value boolValue]){
...
```

If we already know that value is number, why should we bother to call that method? In Obj-C any condition that is !=0 will evaluate to TRUE, and when its ==0 will evaluate to NO.

Comment: Sounds like you're confused by the difference between objects and primitive types.  `value` is a pointer.  It may point to something (have a non-zero value), but the value it's encapsulating may be zero (false).

Comment: @Avi, well, we could write then if([value integerValue]), there would be the same result as far as i understand.

Comment: It would be the same for every architecture that Objective-C will ever run on.  It's more a matter of expressing intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSNumber is a wrapper for primitive values. So, if you wraps a Boolean like this:

```
NSNumber *b = @(YES);
```

You will get an object with the value `YES` (or TRUE) inside it. But you can do the same for `NO`. So, no matter if you have `YES` or `NO`, the object will always return a non-nil object. That's why makes sense to unwrap the `NSNumber` value with the `boolValue` method.

Answer (score 2):

When you know which value you have in your `NSNumber` object you should then convert it to specific type to get the value back.

For e.g.

```
NSNumber *a = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

You know that you've a boolean in your number object (a).

So you can check it like this,

```
if([a boolValue]) {
    //This means TRUE or true or YES or 1
} else {
    //This means FALSE or false or NO or 0
}
```

Now consider this case,

```
NSNumber *b = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:5];
```

In this number you've an integer in your number object (b).

To get its value, you can do it like this:

```
NSInteger value = [b integerValue];
```

There're some other ways to write an number object

For e.g.

```
NSNumber *c = @YES; //@NO;

NSNumber *d = @(YES); //@(NO);
```

here, c and d both are same. Brackets are only used for stylistic.

Answer (score 1):

Because `NSNumber` is an object that holds a number (or boolean).  Any object can be `nil` (uninitialised) and that isn't the same as it holding integer `0` or  boolean `NO`.

Therefore:

```
NSNumber *a = @(NO);
NSNumber *b = nil;
if (a != b) {
    // Always true
}
```

Comment: Just `@NO`, don't need brackets.

Comment: @Cy-4AH It's a stylistic choice.